# API Facebook return null with getBirthday()

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook

Hi I'm programming on Android with SDK Android, Eclipse and API Facebook. I use this code to get the birthday.

```
public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
    if (user != null) {
        user.getBirthday();
```

But getBirthday returns null.

I need know user's birthday. I try it get the JSON with this code:

```
JSONObject json = user.getInnerJSONObject();
```

Inspecting JSON, date doesn't appear. What can I do to get the birthday?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have enough permission to access birthday?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/

Make sure you have it first, then try your code again